# Object's origin moves with 3D cursor

Tags: origin, 3d-cursor

This is an unfamiliar behavior but it may just be that I'm working differently than usual.

When I set an object's origin to the 3D Cursor and then move the cursor, the object's origin moves with it. My mirror modifiers then reflect that change.  I don't remember this as being the way that it worked.  Have I accidentally set origins to be locked to the cursor, or is that just the way that it's always been?  I'm wanting to set the origin to a specific vertex on the object and have that origin stay relative to that vertex regardless of the object's position or orientation.  I seem to remember an option to "Set Origin to Selected" but can't find that in 3.2.1

EDIT:
On closer examination, it appears that the origin snaps back to the 3D cursor after being moved.  It snaps once the object is selected again after the move.
[image: Snapping Origin]

Comment: The menu "Object" >> "Set Origin" will allow you to adjust to where.   But I'm not thinking of any way where an origin will then track the movement of the 3D Cursor.  I assume you are in Object mode.

Comment: Please see the edit above.

Comment: Not sure why it would cause the effect that you're seeing, but I assume you know that you have snapping turned on ? (Horseshoe-shaped icon in the centre of the top toolbar.)

Comment: Yes, but it happens whether snapping is on or off.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Apply All Transforms*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little late, but your origin is following the cursor because in the "Transform Pivot Point" you have the "3D Cursor" option active.

Answer (score -1):

You go into *Edit Mode*, select the vertex you want to set as origin, hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> and it will bring you a pop-up menu.

You will want to hit *Cursor to Selected*, now go back into *Object Mode* and right click. Go to *Set Origin*, and click *Origin to 3d Cursor*.