# Why is object origin stuck to 3D cursor? How to get it unstuck?

Tags: objects, origin, empty

Why is the origin of this empty stuck on the 3D cursor? How do I get it unstuck?
Setting the origin to geometry doesn’t fix it. Thanks. Blender 3.2.2, Windows 11
[Blend](https://www.arcadiastreet.com/share/origin_stuck_on_3d_cursor.blend)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the origin isn't "stuck on the 3d cursor" in your case like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271101/objects-origin-moves-with-3d-cursor) case.  I see the little orange dot (orange dot) is at the center of the empty and moves with it.

Instead your have your *Transform [Pivot Point](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html)* set to 3d Cursor, instead of something like *Individual [object] Origins*  Or *Active Element*.

[image]

Indeed it is so easy to get disoriented and get blender "off kilter" with so many dials and settings!

Comment: That's it! Yes, it's always something with Blender. Thank you!

Comment: @WilburPost I attribute my loss of hair to frustrating moments with such a complex piece of software; not much better in 3ds Max.  We need the "read my mind" interface that's coming in 2035.

Comment: Wow.
30 second fix.
I was panicking for nothing! Thanks!